# nginx Ingress and cloud provider load balancer like (ALB) really a load balancer in Kubernetes world?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-pod, nginx-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

**nginx Ingress** is mainly used for *path based routing* and *sub domain based routing* to route the request to particular pod and **Cloud provider load balancer** will provide external ip address to get the requests from external world and which in turn points to ingress.

In Kubernetes, **Service components** acts as a real load balancer by balancing the load to multiple pods in the cluster. This is my understanding, Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are correct, so the flow goes like

You create the LB on any Cloud provider which gives you endpoint to the **internet** you can use it with ingress controller. (You can further use the SSL/TLS certificate also with LB to run HTTPS)

If you are using the **Nginx ingress controller** or any other controller depending on that it will handle or manage the **Ingress resource** in the cluster.

Once ingress rule decide service to forward traffic, K8s internal service load balance the traffic across running PODs for specific deployment based on rule.

```
internet > Loadbalancer > ingress > ingress controller checks > service > Loadbalance traffic across avilable POD of that specific service
```

Default load balancing will be round robbin.

Comment: But, Why is it named as load balancer(ALB) if it just forwards the request to ingress controller. Which is confusing

Comment: it's types of LoadBalancer that you are using you can also use the NLB with the cluster.

Comment: do read more about type of LB here : https://medium.com/paul-zhao-projects/difference-in-between-aws-alb-nlb-and-clb-19b6048b3e6d

Comment: you can use ALB or NLB as per the requirement with Kubernetes cluster and it will forward the request further to ingress and all.